# Why white screen stuck after splash screen in Ionic 4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I run `ionic cordova run android` for my Ionic Cordova project. At this time, I have my mobile connected to PC via USB. So when I run that command, it installs the app on my real device Android Redmi Note 6 PRO.

But what really happens is when the app opens, only white screen appears, nothing else at all. First it shows splash screen and then white screen forever. Why does this behaviour happen? I read somewhere that some people had this problem because of Ionic 4.

Below are my logcat logs from after I click the app to open on Android emulator (it shows white screen also on Android emulator).

```
2019-02-11 00:01:24.131 5945-5945/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-02-11 00:01:24.148 5945-5945/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-02-11 00:01:24.312 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/CordovaLog: Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
2019-02-11 00:01:24.312 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/CordovaActivity: Apache Cordova native platform version 7.1.4 is starting
2019-02-11 00:01:24.312 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaActivity: CordovaActivity.onCreate()
2019-02-11 00:01:24.342 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 61.0.3163.98 (code 316409812)
2019-02-11 00:01:24.350 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/zygote: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2019-02-11 00:01:24.392 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 8 ms (timestamps 2894-2902)
2019-02-11 00:01:24.421 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(136)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
2019-02-11 00:01:24.422 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "61.0.3163.98", actual native library version number "61.0.3163.98"
2019-02-11 00:01:24.436 5945-5963/io.ionic.starter W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, sandboxed = true
2019-02-11 00:01:24.464 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false
2019-02-11 00:01:24.513 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/o.ionic.starter: type=1400 audit(0.0:48): avc: denied { read } for name="vmstat" dev="proc" ino=4026532039 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2019-02-11 00:01:24.544 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-11 00:01:24.553 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa4516160: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-02-11 00:01:24.555 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa4516160: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x94123730)
2019-02-11 00:01:24.635 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/IonicWebViewEngine: Ionic Web View Engine Starting Right Up 1...
2019-02-11 00:01:24.659 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebViewEngine: CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Google
2019-02-11 00:01:24.675 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/PluginManager: init()
2019-02-11 00:01:24.718 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
2019-02-11 00:01:24.787 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
2019-02-11 00:01:24.793 5945-5963/io.ionic.starter I/cr_LibraryLoader: Using linker: org.chromium.base.library_loader.ModernLinker
2019-02-11 00:01:24.795 5945-5992/io.ionic.starter W/cr_media: Requires BLUETOOTH permission
2019-02-11 00:01:24.800 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaActivity: Started the activity.
2019-02-11 00:01:24.805 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
2019-02-11 00:01:24.834 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-02-11 00:01:24.834 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-02-11 00:01:24.836 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-02-11 00:01:24.836 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-02-11 00:01:24.856 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa48062c0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-02-11 00:01:24.871 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.188 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.209 5945-6010/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x94170560: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-02-11 00:01:25.212 5945-6010/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x94170560: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x92f2a180)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.302 5945-6010/io.ionic.starter I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
2019-02-11 00:01:25.302 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.313 5945-6010/io.ionic.starter W/cr_MediaCodecUtil: HW encoder for video/avc is not available on this device.
2019-02-11 00:01:25.372 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.450 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.458 5945-6010/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x941716a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-02-11 00:01:25.460 5945-6010/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x941716a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x92f2a180)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.537 5945-6012/io.ionic.starter W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
2019-02-11 00:01:25.537 5945-5950/io.ionic.starter I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=22KB, data=30KB
2019-02-11 00:01:25.541 5945-5950/io.ionic.starter I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=22KB, data=30KB
2019-02-11 00:01:25.541 5945-5950/io.ionic.starter I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
2019-02-11 00:01:25.546 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageDidNavigate(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.611 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.619 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageDidNavigate(http://localhost/)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.619 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/
2019-02-11 00:01:25.640 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/runtime.js
2019-02-11 00:01:25.641 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/polyfills.js
2019-02-11 00:01:25.644 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/styles.js
2019-02-11 00:01:25.645 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/cordova.js
2019-02-11 00:01:25.646 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/vendor.js
2019-02-11 00:01:25.647 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/main.js
2019-02-11 00:01:25.663 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/: Line 10 : The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.
2019-02-11 00:01:25.663 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(10)] "The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.", source: http://localhost/ (10)
2019-02-11 00:01:25.997 5945-5991/io.ionic.starter E/chromium: [ERROR:service_manager.cc(156)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::BudgetService exposed by: content_browser
2019-02-11 00:01:26.012 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/JsMessageQueue: Set native->JS mode to EvalBridgeMode
2019-02-11 00:01:26.083 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/cordova_plugins.js
2019-02-11 00:01:26.101 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/www/statusbar.js
2019-02-11 00:01:26.102 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-device/www/device.js
2019-02-11 00:01:26.106 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js
2019-02-11 00:01:26.107 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/src/www/util.js
2019-02-11 00:01:26.108 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/plugins/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/www/android/keyboard.js
2019-02-11 00:01:26.201 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2019-02-11 00:01:26.213 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:26.268 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:27.505 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:27.812 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2019-02-11 00:01:27.826 5945-5999/io.ionic.starter D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa48062c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa48038d0)
2019-02-11 00:01:27.878 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2019-02-11 00:01:27.887 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/main.js: Line 3385 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null
2019-02-11 00:01:27.887 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3385)] "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null", source: http://localhost/main.js (3385)
2019-02-11 00:01:27.894 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/SystemWebChromeClient: http://localhost/vendor.js: Line 75947 : Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 973 ms
2019-02-11 00:01:27.895 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(75947)] "Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 973 ms", source: http://localhost/vendor.js (75947)
2019-02-11 00:01:27.896 5945-5988/io.ionic.starter D/SERVER: Handling local request: http://localhost/assets/icon/favicon.png
2019-02-11 00:01:27.916 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2019-02-11 00:01:27.924 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter D/CordovaWebViewImpl: onPageFinished(http://localhost/)
2019-02-11 00:01:27.951 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
2019-02-11 00:01:28.063 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter I/chatty: uid=10080(io.ionic.starter) identical 3 lines
2019-02-11 00:01:28.110 5945-5945/io.ionic.starter W/zygote: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Chrome debugger shows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null
    at vendor.js:88820
    at NgRedux.push../node_modules/ng2-redux/lib/components/ng-redux.js.NgRedux.configureStore (vendor.js:87925)
    at new AppModule (main.js:1511)
    at _createClass (vendor.js:56970)
    at _createProviderInstance (vendor.js:56940)
    at initNgModule (vendor.js:56873)
    at new NgModuleRef_ (vendor.js:57600)
    at createNgModuleRef (vendor.js:57589)
    at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (vendor.js:59420)
    at NgModuleFactory_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleFactory_.create (vendor.js:60124)
vendor.js:75947 Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 776 ms
```

Comment: Is there any error in console, white screen usually indicates something failed instantly, been there many times :D

Comment: ionic serve or ionic lab works so fine. everything works like a charm for these two commands. but when i run it on actual device, it's stuck on white screen. I pasted pastebin . that's logs I guess. no?

Comment: I mean the console... Chrome has in developer tabs `Remote Devices`, so while your device is connected to your pc you can inspect the console just like web developing :)  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: I found the error , but doesn't make any sense. here it is  https://pastebin.com/EzdyV3Tw

Comment: Some issue with your plugin `ng2-redux`. When quickly googling, that plugin has been deprecated probably pretty long. Probably some issue of compatibility (if it even ever was compatible with ionic?), is just a guess. Apparently works in browser for you, but the build for device is different, so this can happen. Since you are using ionic, there are also redux plugins specifically made for ionic, so I would suggest one of those. I know it's a hassle to change in middle of development, but that is my suggestion. Or then you just have to google the error message and try to find a solution.

Comment: I fixed it. it was because of devtools extension which only works on browsers.

Comment: By the way, which plugin did you find for specifically ionic? i google and i couldn't find any redux plugin for ionic.

Comment: Sorry, I have found just one, can't remember the name, and didn't find it now when I did a quick search. But what I have used is ngrx-store + the ngrx-ionic-storage plugin. So I mixed those up :D

Comment: i tried ngrx-store and works like a charm.

Comment: cool! Yeah, it's a nice lib, and the ionic-storage is easy to integrate if needed, just a few lines! :)

Comment: by the way check out my other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638321/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-many-nested-switchmap . it really worries me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I’ve solved this issue by setting the correct parameters on config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

Then, on my `platform.ready()` instruction all I do is `Splashscreen.hide()` and after that run the project on android using.

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Comment: Tried this as well but still shows white screen and no error in the console. Here is my question which i raised hope someone helps me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982251/white-screen-ionic-v6-11-8-capacitor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49913377/ionic-3-long-white-screen-after-splash/49915971#49915971

Answer (score 10):

Found solution. Problem was in [cordova-plugin-android-permissions](https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions). On android 6+ (maybe android 5 too, I don’t have it on my devices) user should accept permissions manually. In application permissions request looks like alert view. And this alert automatically stops splashscreen (even if you don’t hide splashscreen automatically and don’t call hide method yet) and broke fade out animation. Also this permissions request broke splashscreen even if permissions already added.

So solution is to request permissions after splashScreen.hide() after timeout delay equal to fade out timeout.

example:
config.xml

```
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

In app.components.ts

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

> **NOTED!!!** the setTimeout delay should be equal to
>   FadeSplashScreenDuration param value in config.xml

**Conclusion:**
The code above made the smooth transition from the Splash screen, that will fade smoothly to you start up page. No white screen is shown at all. Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 7):

If changing `config.xml` did not work for you, **TRY THIS**

**Step 1** :
Open `index.html`
Change the base href from `<base href="/" />` to `<base href="./" />`

**Step 2:** 
Open `tsconfig.json` 
Change the target in compilerOptions from `"target": "es2015"` to `"target": "es5"`

Reference: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1878#issuecomment-523497238

Comment: Mine was es2020. I changed it to es2015 and es5. Both worked for me

Comment: Come someone explain the reason why `<base href="/" />` to `<base href="./" />` would change anything ? I'm not sur I do understand that trick

Answer (score 6):

I also faced this problem, but in my case, the problem is with default routing.

When App initializes it tries to open on default route that is Empty route, which further we redirect to the actual working route, In my case Empty route was redirected to "/dashboard".

Example code

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },
  { 
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './public/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' 
  }
]
```

In the above code, my Empty route is redirecting to dashboard where [AuthGuard] is active, and it stuck in circulation, So I decided it redirect to the route where [AuthGuard] is not active, That is "/login" in my case.
Updated code by redirecting to login where [Authgaurd] is not active.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule'
      },
      { 
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './public/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' 
      }
 ]
```

After building the project for Andriod, The app runs successfully.

Justed posted the answer if anyone has this issue same like me on the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your config.xml file

```
<preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

then run this command: **ionic cordova build android**
it will generate an apk file here: your_project_folder/platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

This should work with no white screen stucked after splash screen

Answer (score 1):

**config.xml**

```
 <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" /> 
 <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

**main.js**
please change

```
this.platform.ready().then(function () {
        _this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        _this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
```

to

```
this.platform.ready().then(function () {
            _this.statusBar.styleDefault();
            setTimeout(function(){
                _this.splashScreen.hide();

            }, 3000);
        });
```

Comment: It's probably OK to add comments in your answer to explain why it is better than other techniques, but generalised remarks about it being "the best answer" are unsubstantiated and vague. It is best to still to neutral technical writing unless you can explain why your approach is better than another one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still down here without an answer here is how I solved it.

```
$ ionic cordova run android --simulator --verbose --optimization=false
```

If it builds, runs and then goes to a white screen, set up chrome for developer mode and then open the following page.

[chrome://inspect/#devices](http://chrome://inspect/#devices)

Check the console logs for any errors, and fix them as required. The strange thing was it would work perfectly well in the normal web browser.

Note: the --optimization=false flag is important to allow you to read the errors easily.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Debug your app and check if its showing any error app stuck at white screen mainly because of errors in app

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was something related to android platform config. I did following to resolve the issue:

1. Delete `android` folder(in your project directory or under platforms directory.)
2. Run command to add android as platform.

> npx cap add android

Above command is for ionic with Capacitor. You can use regular command if you are using cordova.

3. Open Android Studio and create APK. This APK should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

since this topic comes up while searching for the white screen, all of the above solution didn't work for me, but what did work was this:

1. delete the android folder
2. delete the www folder
3. run: ionic capacitor add android
4. run: ionic build (this will create the www folder with all needed html and js files in it)
5. run: npx cap sync
6. run: npx cap open andorid
7. run the project on your phone.

that's it.