# Is it bad practice to use many nested switchMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have HTTP interceptor. In that interceptor, before I change the request, I need a loader to turn be turned on.
**What really worries me is that I end up having lots of `switchMap`s.**

why?

1. loader is asynchronous
2. I also need to translate the message passing from interceptor to loader service. Translating messages is also asynchronous. In interceptor, I should run the request when loader and translating finishes

**What I do in my loader service**

```js
public showLoader(message) {
    return this.translateService.get(message).pipe(
        switchMap((translatedMessage) => {
            this.loader$ = from(
                this.loadingController.create({ message: translatedMessage })
            );
            return this.loader$.pipe(
                switchMap((loader) => {
                    return from(loader.present());
                })
            );
        })
    );
}
```

**in my interceptor**

```js
public intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
  return this.loaderService.showLoader("WAITING").pipe(
     take(1),
     switchMap( ()=>{
```

so there are already 3 nested `switchMap`s. And below it, I need 2 or 3 more `switchMap`s (one for getting tokens from storage and one for something else). Basically end up having 5 `switchMap`s.

**Question: Is nesting all these `switchMap`s considered an anti-pattern?**

Comment: Just a thought, but since you have to wait on the translation service, you could probably flatten this out quite a bit using async/await.

Comment: Don't nest them if you don't need to. In your first snippet, you could easily move the inner switchMap into the outer pipe. Otherwise, no, it's not a bad practise as there are no alternatives to chaining these

Comment: if a call it's not async, use map, not switchMap -e.g. I imagine that this.loadingControler.create and loader.present() are sync functions-

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to use many `switchMap` especially when you need asynchronous behaviour, the bad practice is to touch things outside of the data stream.

In your code `this.loader$` is an example of it, instead of using variables outside of a stream try to build a pipe that does everything you want inside of itself.

You can even omit `from` if `this.loadingController.create` and `loader.present` are `Promise` like, `switchMap` supports `Observable`, `Promise`, `Array` and `Iterator`.

Your code could be like that

```js
    public showLoader(message) {
        return this.translateService.get(message).pipe(
            switchMap(translatedMessage => this.loadingController.create({message: translatedMessage})),
            switchMap(loader => loader.present()),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Indeed, nothing wrong with chaining many switchMaps, and good suggestion to omit the `from` and `of` as they are not needed in this case.