# Ionic android white screen after splash screen Ionic v4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

**Info**

Ionic - v4

Cordova - 8.1.2

Cordova-android : 7.1.1

@ionic/angular: 4.0.0-rc.1

Though this is a duplicate of previously asked question I still can't figure out the issue in my case so I am asking it again.

Without --release --prod my APK works fine but when building for production I get the white screen forever.

**I have tried the below steps**

- Added `<preference name=“loadUrlTimeoutValue” value=“700000” />` in config.xml
- Tried hiding splash screen after timeout
- Tried renaming index to main and added window.location in index file
- Tried removing cordova android platform and reinstalling
- Removed the node modules folder and reinstalled
- Reinstalled all cordova plugins
- Also added super.loadurl in mainactivity file
- Changed base href to “.” from “/”

But nothing worked and when i build using the below command

**ionic cordova build android --prod**

I get an app-debug apk which i debugged using chrome remote debugging and I get the below errors

[image]

Comment: Most likely there is some error in JS during run-time. You can debug this using either browser or the Android emulator. You can look for information in [Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/search?q=blank%20screen)

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh But I can build a production apk without any errors ?

Comment: Yes, but during run-time there could be problems with assets/JS files. Build the production build and run it in a browser website. Notice if browser throws any error in console. If everything works fine, try [debugging in the emulator](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/debugging-on-emulator/111202).

Comment: @SujitKumarSingh The screenshot I have attached is the result of chrome remote debugging.

Comment: There are 2 errors. 1. Error related with dependency of some service. 2. cordova-plugin-calendar is not present. Re-add the [calendar plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/calendar#installation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why white screen stuck after splash screen in Ionic 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620514/why-white-screen-stuck-after-splash-screen-in-ionic-4)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and for those who face the similar issue kindly check your dependency.In my case I didn't add the network ionic plugin in my app.module.ts providers.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
 "build:ios": "ionic cordova build ios --prod --release --aot --minifyjs --optimizejs --minifycss",
"build:android": "ionic cordova build android --prod --release --aot --minifyjs --optimizejs --minifycss",
```