# white screen ionic v6.11.8 capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor, android-studio-4.2

As i'm trying to run the app via capacitor using the command below.

```
ionic capacitor run android
```

as it runs in the **android studio 4.2 canary 11** successfully when i run my emulator on pixel or via mobile USB debug mode it gives me ***white screen*** after capacitor splash screen. If i use chrome `chrome://inspect/#devices` it shows my app running and as i see my console it also shows me `console.log('dangggggggggggg');` which is inside the `initializeApp()` but i only see white screen. I have gone through many pages for help but still i can't figure out whats the issue of it as chrome debugger doesn't show error in it as well. Here is a screen shot below.
[image: white screen]

Here are the Url's which i followed.
[Why white screen stuck after splash screen in Ionic 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620514/why-white-screen-stuck-after-splash-screen-in-ionic-4)

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/white-screen-when-using-capacitor/183825/3

https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/960

As i'm using android canary not regular studio because of AMD processor.

Comment: People doesn't know the answer but negative marking is essential for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my Routing from 'home' which pointed to blank the page, to the page which i needed to see. Was a really confusing issue but it lied in my angular app routing altogether.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-v5-capacitor-white-screen/196825/3

Here is my code below which pointed to blank page.

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home', // It pointed to the blank page
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'recipes', // Used this to run the start page and it worked
    children:[{
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./recipes/recipes.module').then(m => m.RecipesPageModule)
    },
    {
      path: ':recipeId',
      loadChildren: () => import('./recipes/recipe-detail/recipe-detail.module').then(m => m.RecipeDetailPageModule)
    }
  ]
  m.RecipesPageModule)
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

for me the issue was with `webDir` prop in `capacitor.config.json`, replaced to be `www` then it worked.

[Ionic Capacitor App Blank/White Screen Problem](https://medium.com/@ahmetsezen/ionic-capacitor-app-blank-white-screen-problem-98c0e47ff2d4)

Comment: God bless you, you saved my as$.

Comment: In my case I had to change it to "dist"

Answer (score 0):

With Angular version 14.1.3 and ionic 6.20.1 I solved the blank page by modifying the compiler target to es2017 in compilerOptions in file **tsconfig.json**.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
```